# Difference value and start in html lists

Tags: html

I am trying to learn html from the beginning. I learned the most important attributes and are now on the ones for lists.

type, start, value and compact

I understand type and start.

However, I do not see any difference between what start and value do. I can only see a difference on when to write/type it. Is that correct?

That is, if I want a list to start on number 7, I'd write:

```
<ol start="7">
    <li>Enero</li>
    <li>Febrero</li>
    <li>Marzo</li>
</ol>
```

And I can do the same thing writing it like this:

```
<ol>
    <li value="7">Enero</li>
    <li>Febrero</li>
    <li>Marzo</li>
</ol>
```

As I say, they do the same thing. Am I missing something? Or shall I just use whichever want I want since there's no real difference?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#attr-ol-start) says:

> The `start` attribute, if present, must be a [valid integer](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#valid-integer) giving
>   the [ordinal value](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#ordinal-value) of the first list item.
>
> [...] The first item in the list has the [ordinal value](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#ordinal-value) given by the
>   [`ol`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ol-element) element's [`start`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#attr-ol-start) attribute, unless that [`li`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element)
>   element has a [`value`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#attr-li-value) attribute with a value that can be
>   successfully parsed, in which case it has the [ordinal value](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#ordinal-value) given
>   by that [`value`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#attr-li-value) attribute.
>
> Each subsequent item in the list has the [ordinal value](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#ordinal-value) given by
>   its [`value`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#attr-li-value) attribute, if it has one, or, if it doesn't, the
>   [ordinal value](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#ordinal-value) of the previous item, plus one if the
>   [`reversed`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#attr-ol-reversed) is absent, or minus one if it is present.

Therefore, yes, specifying a `start` attribute and no `value` is the same as specifying the `value` of the first `li` and no `start`.